# aligning divs and changing depending on screen size

Tags: html, css

On my website I am trying to have an image with a corresponding block of text displayed to its right. I will be repeating these lots of times (essentially it is a list of images with a corresponding paragraph of text for each image in the list). When the screen size is 736 px I would like the block of text to be displayed below the image instead of to the side and the image to be centered. I chose 736 px as I think this will capture tablets and phones.

For this I have been playing around with div tags and the @media query.  For desktops I have the image at 20% width and the text at 80% next to each other. When the size of the browser changes to 736px I would like the image to be 50% and the text to be 100% and displayed underneath the image.

As soon as I started playing with @media I hit a wall and can’t see what is wrong. Is anyone able to advise?

Also, what would I need to add so that I could then copy and paste the html, change the image and text and have them displayed below the previous ones? Am I correct in thinking that it should just do this automatically?

CSS:

```
 div.sidebyside{


    @media only screen and (max-width : 736px){

        border: 5px solid #000000;

    }

    @media only screen and (min-width : 737px){

        float:left;
        border: 5px solid #000000;

    }

}

div#image{

    @media only screen and (max-width : 736px){

        width : 50%;
        align-items: center;

    }


    @media only screen and (min-width : 737px){

        width : 20%;

    }

}


div#info{


    @media only screen and (max-width : 736px){

        width : 100%;

    }


    @media only screen and (min-width : 737px){

        width : 70%;
        padding-left: 5%;   

    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="image" class="sidebyside"><img src="url" alt="" /></div>
<div id="info" class="sidebyside">
<p style="text-align: justify;">Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Donec sed odio dui. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Is that really CSS?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yep. But very low quality. Please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @K.Daniek Nopes. Still not sure if it is valid.

Comment: @PraveenKumar You mean e.g. `div#info`? It's... archaic, but works somehow.

Comment: @K.Daniek Dude, I meant `@media` inside `{}`. Does it work?

Comment: Hey, sorry I am a noob with this stuff. I got that from a youtube video I watched.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Didn't notice that, dude. It doesn't work actually.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS works, thanks very much for your help :)

```
        div.sidebyside{

        float:left;
        border: 5px solid #000000;
    }

    div#image{

        width : 20%;
    }


    div#info{

        width : 70%;
        padding-left: 5%;

    }


    @media (max-width: 768px) {

        div#image{

width: 50%;         
margin-left: 25% ;
            margin-right: 25% ;
        }


        div#info{

            width : 100%;
            padding-left: 0%;

        }

    }
```